# Visual studio on Raspberry pi not working properly (TAb, CTRL+M, DEL, backspace not working)

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I'm using a raspbian Linux on a raspberry pi 4 2GB Ram through a VNC link to code C++ directly on it and control the GPIO pins.

I was coding with Geany until now which was working very fine, but it isn't really "evolved", therefore I wanted to switch to the Visual Studio Code

- When I tried to "TAB" a line to indent it, it did not work.
- Apparently, the solution is to press CTRL+M for switching the "Tab key moves focus"... Which did not work.
- I passed through the console to find the CTRL+M command and when activating it this way, nothing changes.
- I went to the "shortcut definition" and when I press "CTRL+M" it is detected as "CTRL+SHIFT"
- In the same idea, I tried to indent with CTRL+[ with no effect.
- Also, backspace and DEL are not working... DEL opens the "rename" function menu

Of course, all these were working with Geany.

VS Code seems to be a very nice upgrade compared to the Geany, but I'd like it to work properly with it.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you trying to use VScode on Raspberry? I think vscode code is very heavy for raspy. maybe try more lightweight text editors like: VIM, nano, Geany

Comment: @Giorgi Imerlishvili The Rpi is heating up, but it works, just it's bugged, and I don't know what to do

Comment: Do you know that you can run vscode on your PC and remotely debug/run the code on your pi?

Comment: @balun probably, I'm passing through a vnc link to control directly the Rpi and test the code on it (I play with GPIO pins mostly), so the most convinient for me is to code directly on the Rpi...